# Calling a static method on a class known by name?

Tags: php

Is there any way to obtain this effect in a PHP version **prior** to 5.3?

```
class A {
  public static function x() {print 'ok'; }
}

$className = 'A';
$className::x();
```

Thanks!
Palantir

Comment: something's fishy with your code. either make x static, or make $className an instance of A

Comment: ouch, sure, x is to be static!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can by using call_user_func_array :

```
call_user_func_array(array($className, 'x'), array()) ;
```

Comment: I was out to lunch, now all the comments are "1 hour ago" and I don't know who was the first, so I'll accept the one with lowest rep. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 2):

```
$className = 'A'; 
call_user_func(array($className,'x'));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
call_user_func(array($className,'x'));
```

see http://cz.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php